# How to define mapping of Geo_Points in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can anybody please tell me what is the correct way of mapping a geo_point in elasticsearch, i also want to index lats and longs seperately, from below two declarations which is correct

```
location          : {"type":"geo_point", "lat_lon": "true"},
```

OR

```
location          : {"type":"geo_point", "lat_lon": "true"
                  lat: { type:"double"},
                  lon: { type: "double"}
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lat_lon: Set to true to also index the .lat and .lon as fields. Defaults to false. ([link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-geo-point-type.html#_mapping_options))

So you should use the first solution.

[Example](https://www.found.no/play/gist/8989aa38d674d5ee4585)